# Fit a function for these values.

Tags: functions

This was asked to me in a interview its not a homework problem. I really wish my school would have given me such quality homework ;)

Find out f(x) such that
f(1) = 3
f(2) = 6
f(3) = 10

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LagrangeInterpolatingPolynomial.html

Comment: did they give some hints?

Comment: @DonAntonio I was given like 30 seconds to answer that and since I was applying for a java developer's post at a web site designing firm I highly doubt it that they intended me to do lagrange's interpolation.

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik Nope that guy was really very busy he didn't let me speak at all.

Comment: As you can see @user2340452, AJ's answer is one possibility, and there are infinite ones without further conditions on $\;f\;$

Comment: I think, given the time constraint and the nature of your job, my answer would have probably been acceptable.

Comment: well I understand that they have given me very little constraints. But my friend came up with this possible solution. 2^x + ceiling function( (x+1) / x). I haven't yet learnt latex so I apologize for typing out equations like this.

Comment: If your friend came up with that in 30 seconds, (s)he's a savant.

Comment: He came up with that in 10 seconds flat. But lets keep things on topic. I was looking for a more simpler equations and more intuitive solutions !

Comment: $3x+\left\lfloor\frac{x}{3}\right\rfloor$

Comment: Why don't you post that as a solution @AJStas !

Comment: I already posted a solution.  I'll post another if you insist lol

Answer (score 4):

$$
f(x) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
3 & \quad x = 1 \\
6 & \quad x = 2 \\
10 & \quad x = 3 \\
0 & \quad x\neq1,2,3
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$

OR
$$3x+\left\lfloor\frac{x}{3}\right\rfloor$$

Comment: :D at your first solution....... this is what i have thought just after looking at the question :D

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik Whenever I see questions on here about what function would fit a given set of points, and they don't specify anything else, I always give these types of answers.  They are the simplest and very easy to construct.

Answer (score 1):

If they wanted a continuous function... One thing I might remember is that any $n+1$ points (with different $x$-values) determines a degree $n$ polynomial. So we might guess that $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ for some $a,b,c$.

Plugging in the given values gives a system of 3 linear equations in 3 unknowns $a,b,c$ (which may or may not take you more than 30 seconds to solve!)

**Added** Another thing I might have noticed is that $3,6,10$ are the 2nd, 3rd and 4th triangular numbers, so $f(x)=\frac{(x+1)(x+2)}{2}$ works (which gives the same solution as the previous one actually).

Answer (score 1):

You might give a hand by using Maple as follows:

```
[> with(CurveFitting):
   PolynomialInterpolation([[1, 3], [2, 6], [3, 10]], x);

                              (1/2)x^2+(3/2)x+1
```

[image]